# Yii - formatting GET url created by form submisson

Tags: forms, yii, format, submit, parameters

Can i change the URL format generated by a Yii form submisson?

eg. my url using the get method will look like:

domain/search/new?Search[field_1]=1&Search[field_2]=2&Search[field_3]=3

can i make it look like:

domain/search/new/1/2/3 or

domain/search/new/field_1:1/field_2:2/field_3:3 or

domain/search/new/field_1/1/field_2/2/field_3/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you let the browser submit the form normally.

On the other hand, if you use jQuery to prevent the form submission and make a custom AJAX request (or even point the browser to another URL) instead then you can do anything you like.

Comment: What do you mean by point the browser to another URL? I want the system to make a search and be able to share the results via the get request in the location bar. Can you change the browser URL to something else with AJAX without reloading the page?

Comment: @Simba: If you change the URL the page will reload *unless* you only change the `#fragment` part at the end. So you can actually have an URL that describes the search (strictly as part of the fragment) but does not cause a reload -- and if you complement that with making the search and displaying the results with AJAX you can have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @Simba: Twitter used to do exactly this a while ago, but then they decided that it wasn't a good idea in their case after all.